# JavaFx Controller Initialization Order - Database Called Multiple times

Tags: java, javafx, controller, scenebuilder

I have a standard JavaFX App which extends Application.  The first page I show is a dashboard with buttons to open other apps.  That is all fine, the first app is an admin page called AdminController that lets the user make CRUD operations on the model objects - user, contacts, products each entity is a tab on the admin view - so in my main Admin FXML (Using SceneBuilder) I include the other fxml pages using fx:include the users tab, contacts tab, and products tab.  Again these includes are all in an Admin.fxml with its own controller.

```
<Tab fx:id="contactsTab" onSelectionChanged="#goToContacts" text="Contact">
   <content>
     <fx:include source="/fxml/manager_contacts_tab.fxml" fx:id="contact" />
   </content
<Tab/>
```

My idea was to load the resources each page will need, users/contacts/products in the AdminController so each fx:include I used can use those same objects. Since some of the tabs need all of those resources like users to manage associations and other tabs like product only need a list of products.  My main controller looks like this
I

```
public class AdminController {
  @FXML
  UserController userController;
  @FXML
  ProductController productController;
  @FXML
  ContactController contactController;

@FXML
public void initialize
    // at this point userController already ran, and called DB so it calls it again here
    if (users == null) {
        this.users = FXCollections.observableArrayList(userDao.getAllWithProductsAndContacts());
    }
    if (products == null) {
        this.products = FXCollections.observableArrayList(productDao.getAll());
    }
    if (contacts == null) {
        this.contacts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(contactDao.getAll());
    }
    contactController.setContacts(contact);
    // set other resources, like products
}
```

Logically in my head I would think the initialize method for AdminController will get run first which would allow my to set whatever objects I need to in the child controllers since I can access them, but what is happening is the child controllers get run first, ex. with ContactController

```
public class ContactController {
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        if (contacts == null) {
            this.contacts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(contactDao.getAll());
        }
    }
```

So my apps initialize methods run in the order they were included in the admin.fxml userController, contactController, finally productController

I think my question boils down to how can I share objects between child controllers so that when a new tab is clicked that had the same list of resources the previous one did, a new database call isn't initiated - in my example this happens when I load user page it needs List of Contacts and a List of Products but ContactController & ProductController need those same lists there shouldn't be a need to make another DB call.

Comment: To me it's not 100% clear exactly what you're asking here. What do you mean by a database call? Typically you only query a DB (unless you're modifying it) and that should only take ms to complete. Otherwise (if the database is small enough) you could load it into memory when your program starts and not fetch it at all in your controllers.


By database do you mean a bunch of files that you serialized or are you talking about a SQL database?

Comment: What I typically do with small storage is define a class called "Data" and store ArrayLists in it that hold database objects (like users, products etc). I load those ArrayLists when my program starts. That way your Controllers can just call something like Data.getContacts(); to grab all the contacts. If we're talking a huge database then SQL queries should be run to grab the info.

Comment: Sorry should have clearified - its a SQL database, I think my question than is where to first make the call to the database to get the list of items I am working with - my first thought was do all the database call in the AdminController to set the ChildControllers, but child controllers get initialized before AdminController so at that point the call needs to have been made, and child controllers that share the same list of data aren't visible to each other, ex Contact/Admin Controllers - ContactController needs contacts, but so does UserController (to show associations between the two).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case then if you are loading in "all" the contacts at once I'd probably make the database call BEFORE you initialize a single Controller.

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
        // Database call goes here!
        DatabaseManager.initialize();


        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        // Whatever window initialization stuff you need to do
        window.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Now for your DatabaseManager class

```
package sample;

public class DatabaseManager {

    public static void initialize() {
        // Query the database for your information.
        // Little pseudo code here
        Data.setUsers(Database.userQuery);
        Data.setContacts(Database.contactQuery);
        Data.setProducts(Database.productQuery);
    }

}
```

Now the Data class

```
package sample;

public class Data {

    public static ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public static void setUsers(ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public static void setContacts(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public static void setProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    private static ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    private static ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    private static ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

}
```

Now your controllers only need to call

```
this.contacts = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Data.getContacts());
```

and this will have your arraylist of the contacts ready to go.

Also note that this is what is called "loading it into memory". Another words you are storing all that info in the computer's memory and accessing it from there. This will NOT work for a HUGE database because your computer just won't have the brain space. Anyways, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Right now my application is small enough where this will work - however the plan is it will grow into a large application, do you have any suggestions on larger applications? Ideally I would like to load it only when necessary, but the controller @FXML initialization is confusing me and not operating in the order I would expect.  My expectations where -> AdminController - Load what is needed for the views so views relevant to this Controller i.e ContactController can have access to the AdminControllers contacts - only ContactController is initialized first.

Comment: Well to be honest with you I never did like the "initialize" method of controllers. It was a bit wonky for me too. I'm not sure all of how your program is run  but for me what I've done in all my FX projects is create a "Controller" class and extend all my other controllers from that class and I have a public start() method that i made up myself in that parent class and whenever I load a controller I call the start() method. All the extended controllers override the start() method.

Comment: Thank you Phillip, I appreciate the answers - I will fiddle around with it a bit more and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Fiddled around with it some more and ya why bother, I went with your abstract controller way and it solves my problem, cheers.